# fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store replacement/implementation for std::format

Tags: c++, std, c++20, fmt

It looks like that c++20 `std::format` is not a direct replacement for the fmt library.

Looking at the API (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) it looks like that `fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store` is not part of the standard.

Currently in fmt you can have the following code:

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/args.h>

int main() 
{
  auto store = fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store<fmt::format_context>();
  store.push_back(42);
  store.push_back( std::string { "abc1"} );
  store.push_back(1.5f);
  fmt::vprint("{} this is my {}. This is a number: {}.", store);
}
```

I would like to replace fmt with the standard `std::format`.

I had a very quick look at `fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store` and it looks like it is using a few internal things from fmt so it didn't look that straight forward.

Anyone can provide some guidance on how to implement the above functionality outside of  fmt for C++20 using `std::format` ?

***edit:***

Looking a bit deeper in `fmt:dynamic_format_arg_store` it looks like it is using `detail:make_arg` to create an argument.

I don't know how I can get something equivalent from `std::format` as I only see `std::make_format_args` which returns a different type.

Is `fmt:dynamic_format_arg_store` possible to be implemented for `std:format` without getting into implementation specific details for each compiler ?

Comment: Does it strictly need to be "dynamic"? Can you not use `make_format_args` and pass a static sequence of parameters?

Comment: It has to be dynamic I'm afraid.. I have a background thread popping / deserialising a format string and `n` number of arguments from a queue, then storing them to a `fmt: dynamic_format_arg_store`, which then gets formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot portably implement an equivalent of `fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store` for `std::format` yourself because the representation of `std::basic_format_args` is an implementation detail of the standard library. It might be provided in one of the future versions of the C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vitaut . I kind of realised the same yesterday by giving it a try in MSVC that has `std::format`. This looks like a big limitation of the standard library :(

A simple implementation would be to store `fmt::internal::make_arg<ctx>(arg)` to a fmt_args vector and then use the consturctor `fmt::basic_format_args<ctx>(fmt_args.data(), fmt_args.size()))`. 

But for example those things are missing in MSVC as they are not standardised.

A `std::make_format_arg` and the above constructor would be sufficient to do it if provided by the standard.